# Change the Json Format dynamically

Tags: json, dynatree

My JSON returns something like this

```
        {
    data: "Business & Investing (0)",
    attr: {
    id: "91",
    rel: "file",
    dataitem: null,
    datatext: null
    },
    children: [ ]
    },
    {
    data: "Stock Exchange & Money (0)",
    attr: {
    id: "92",
    rel: "file",
    dataitem: null,
    datatext: null
    },
    children: [ ]
    },
```

i want to change like this "Data" to "title"  brfore passing it to view

```
    {
title: "Business & Investing (0)",
attr: {
id: "91",
rel: "file",
dataitem: null,
datatext: null
},
children: [ ]
},
{
title: "Stock Exchange & Money (0)",
attr: {
id: "92",
rel: "file",
dataitem: null,
datatext: null
},
children: [ ]
},
```

My Dynatree :

```
  function CreateCatTree(filter) {

        $("#res_catBar").dynatree({
            postProcess: function (data, dataType) {
                alert("hey");

            },
            initAjax: {

                type: "GET",                
                cache:false,
                url: '@Url.Action("Catalog")',
                data: {
                    filter:filter
                },
            },
            onActivate: function (node) {

                var id = node.data.attr.id;
                event.preventDefault();
                 retrieveCatalog(id);
                     return false;
            }          
        });

    }
```

Comment: Whatprogramming language do you use to interpret the json?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this in JS:

```js
if (yourJSON.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
    yourJSON["title"] = yourJSON["data"];
    delete yourJSON["data"];
}
```

Comment: Actually I am using Dynatree so it just Takes what ever we passed from Controller. So i think its better to change it in controller

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to use Dynatree:

you may also implement the `postProcess(data, dataType)` callback in JavaScript, and modify the Ajax result there, before it is passed to Dynatree.

Comment: Thanks but for me PostProcess is not being called.

Comment: That's a known bug, just fixed in the trunk (https://code.google.com/p/dynatree/issues/detail?id=473)

Comment: I had done it in other way like creadted another class Dynatree and i binded data from that. Thanks for response anyways but do u know how to perform ajax call file filtering (i mean on key press ) to perform serching the nodes

Answer (score 1):

You should make your own class which has your set of defined properties, and that, then can be serialized through Newtownsoft JSON.

I have a TreeNode.cs

```
public class TreeNode
{

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
```

This is called through a web service as:

```
 List<TreeNode> myTaskListObj = new List<TreeNode>();
```

And then Deserialize or  serializing the data, as needed:

```
        //De Serialize
        myTaskListObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TreeNode>>(jsonString);

        //Serialize 
        jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTaskListObj, Formatting.Indented);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ya i think your will work but in my case i have already done this in JSTREE so now what i want i would like to ask is without changing all can we just change the string data to string title

Comment: If you are getting a handle to the jsonstring, then use regularexpression or any string manipulation to your needs. Since I capture the jsonstring in my webservice, the manipulation would be much easier, and then this modified jsonstring can then be deserialized/serialized. Thx